# can't change font (size, family, line space) in JTextPane

Tags: java, jtextpane

iam making a small note which user can change font size and family also change the line space.
I use this code to set the font size, family, and line space

```
 MutableAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
 StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(set, line);
 StyleConstants.setFontSize(set, font_size);
 StyleConstants.setFontFamily(set, FontFamily);
 JTextPane.setParagraphAttributes(set, true);
```

the problem when i have already a text written in the jtextpane it not change to the fonts i set so i make this to check if the change take effect or not.

```
 MutableAttributeSet s = JTextPane.getInputAttributes();
 float p = StyleConstants.getLineSpacing(s);
 String family = StyleConstants.getFontFamily(s);
 int size = StyleConstants.getFontSize(s);
```

it be same before I change it so what I do it wrong which make my changes not take effect on all the text written in the jtextpane.
also when I checked the font size, family, and line space I found it not change?


**Update**
Thanks to FredK as he said in comment i must select all the text to apply the change on it also i use this code which make it woks

```
    MutableAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(set, line);
    StyleConstants.setFontSize(set, font_size);
    StyleConstants.setFontFamily(set, FontFamily);
    //i use this code to apply the change to all the text 
    StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) MainTextArea.getDocument();
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, doc.getLength() + 1, set, false);

    MainTextArea.setParagraphAttributes(set, true);
```

I used those two lines to apply the change to all text if I selected all without them it will not work. 
I have two problems now
**1 -** if I change font data it on an empty JTextPane it will not take effect so I should write at least one character then select all text to apply the change using first the new code so the change occurs and I can write with the new font.
 I solve it by when the JtextPain is empty I can add any character to it then select all and apply the new font if not empty I use current text so if no one has a better solution we can leave it
**2 -** after the font change using above method when I use the check code to get the current font size, family, and line space it gives me the old font not the applied font on the JtextPan.
I tried to select all then get the font information and it now works too so how can I get the font size, family, and line space as I saved it or edit it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to select all of the text in the JTextPane prior to calling setParagraphAttributes() if you want the new attributes to apply to any existing text.

Comment: check my answer please

Comment: i also should write at least one character to apply the change i don't know why?!